# Dockerfile USER cmd vs Linux su command

Tags: linux, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy db2 express image to docker using non-root user.

The below code is used to start the db2engine using root user, it works fine.

```
FROM ibmoms/db2express-c:10.5.0.5-3.10.0

ENV LICENSE=accept \
    DB2INST1_PASSWORD=password

RUN su - db2inst1 -c "db2start"

CMD ["db2start"]
```

The below code is used to start the db2engine from db2inst1 profile, giving below exception during image build. please help to resolve this.( I am trying to avoid su - command )

```
FROM ibmoms/db2express-c:10.5.0.5-3.10.0

ENV LICENSE=accept \
    DB2INST1_PASSWORD=password

USER db2inst1
RUN /bin/bash -c ~db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2start

CMD ["db2start"]
```

SQL1641N  The db2start command failed because one or more DB2 database manager program files was prevented from executing with root privileges by file system mount settings.

Comment: Make sure that `db2start` is in your `PATH` or use an absolute path to that executable.

Comment: Yes.. I tried with absolute path as well, getting same result.

Comment: Maybe running `./db2start` instead of `db2start` after your `cd` command?

Comment: Yes.. If I use ./db2start, working. but now getting another message now that the db2start cmd failed because one or more db2 db manager program files was prevented from executing with root privileges by file system mount settings

Comment: I have updated my code logic. please check and provide solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your Dockerfile please?

It's worth noting that a `Dockerfile` is used to *build* an image. You can execute commands while building, but once an image is published, running processses are not maintained in the image definition.

This is the reason that the `CMD` directive exists, so that you can tell the container which process to start and encapsulate.

If you're using the pre-existing db2 image from [IBM on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2) (`docker pull ibmcom/db2`), then you will not need to start the process yourself.

Their quickstart guide demonstrates this with the following example command:

```
docker run -itd --name mydb2 --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=<choose an instance password> -e DBNAME=testdb -v <db storage dir>:/database ibmcom/db2
```

As you can see, you only specify the image, and leave the default `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, resulting in the DB starting.

Their recommendation for building your own container on top of theirs (`FROM`) is to load all custom scripts into `/var/custom`, and they will be executed automatically after the main process has started.

Comment: Yes. I aggreged your points.  I am using db2 express c v10 base image.. Now I am facing different issue as I edited my code.. Please share me the solution for my current issue.

Comment: You haven't shown us how you are running the image, or what volumes you have created, which likely play a large part in debugging the file system settings.

Comment: I have updated the code logic. please check and share your solution.